# Creating a multi-column search box in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to create a multi-column search box using the `FILTER` and `SEARCH` function on Google Sheets.

I currently have one sheet called 'Master Client Sheet' with column A through column O and a "Search Tab" sheet where I have the following function:

```
=filter('Master Client Sheet'!A3:N,search(A2,'Master Client Sheet'!A3:A),search(B2,'Master Client Sheet'!B3:B),search(C2,'Master Client Sheet'!C3:C),search(D2,'Master Client Sheet'!D3:D),search(E2,'Master Client Sheet'!E3:E))
```

This makes it so that when I type a certain keyword into the search box, it pulls applicable clients from the master sheet.

When it's just 5 "searches," the function works perfectly fine. But when I try to add more, the function cuts my 180 entries down to half of that.

I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a super simplified example with sample data... showing 1) sample raw data 2) desired output 3) formula with your current output.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10U3xHIOuFyIxNCmtrY27NnepGlQNdeu0VbmpulDQQ_c/edit?usp=sharing @CodeCamper

Comment: @CodeCamper Here is the link of a sample. The search tab pulls from the Master Client Sheet and filters out depending on what is typed in the baby pink rows. For example, it'll narrow down the searches if I'm looking for "Cane Corso" and "Delivery"

Comment: Great, the example appears to be working fine, can you make it so that is does not behave as intended or give me instructions to make it not work as intended?

Comment: The example is fine because has little clients... my actual list has 180 clients and the function only shows 76. I'll see if I can replicate it on my example.

Comment: @CodeCamper if you check now, Master Client sheet has 185 clients, but the search tab only pulls up 19. But if you delete search(E2,'Master Client Sheet'!E3:E) out of A5, then the search tab has 185 entries again.

Comment: Minor Issue: it should be E2:E... that accounts for one missing. Major Issue: having a blank price will return an error on the search function... if you run the search() function on a blank cell it will always return #VALUE

Comment: oh my gosh... thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because search() will always return a #VALUE error if you search a blank cell to resolve this using your existing code you can wrap an array formula and make anything "" equal to " " so that it will not return an error.

```
=arrayformula(filter('Master Client Sheet'!A2:N,search(A2,'Master Client Sheet'!A2:A),search(B2,'Master Client Sheet'!B2:B),search(C2,'Master Client Sheet'!C2:C),search(D2,'Master Client Sheet'!D2:D),search(E2,if('Master Client Sheet'!E2:E=""," ",'Master Client Sheet'!E2:E))))
```

The key addition here is the ArrayFormula and

```
if('Master Client Sheet'!E2:E=""," ",'Master Client Sheet'!E2:E)
```

which is saying if something is blank make it a blank space so that the search function can return a non error result. You will have to wrap this if statement for any column that possibly could contain blank information.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Master Client Sheet'!A2:J), "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 
 IF(A2:J2<>"", "lower(Col"&COLUMN(A2:J2)&") contains '"&LOWER(A2:J2)&"'", )), 0), 
 "no such data"))
```

[image: 0]